# Proving a statement about idempotent matrices

Tags: matrices, proof-writing

I don't know how to prove the following statement:

> Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ be idempotent ($A^2 = A$). Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the following holds: $A^n = A$.

I think a plausible way to prove this is by using induction. But I'm not sure how to conduct such a proof since my induction skills are a bit fuzzy.

Answer (score 1):

By induction (starting from $n=2$ since for $n=1$ you know that $A^1=A$ trivially for any matrix):

- Base case: $n=2$. You are given that $A^2=A$.
- Induction step. Let $A^n=A$, then $$A^{n+1}=\underbrace{A^n}_{=A}\cdot A=A\cdot A=A^2=A$$